# Using different analyzers on Zend Lucene

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-search-lucene

I'm trying to create an index using Zend Lucene.
In Zend's manual (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.extending.html)
it is described how to use a default analyzer:

```
Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(
new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Text());
```

So actually this sets the default analyzer for **all** fields.
Question is:
If i have all kinds of fields, some hold num+string values, some holds regular words.
Can i set a different analyzer for each field?

I see it is possible in java's lucene
http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper.html

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible with the Zend_Lucene extension.

All the fields will be passed through the default analyzer.

You would have to extend the code somehow to specify which analyzer to use for each field or to use the default if none is specified.

Comment: Yeah, its something that I hadn't thought about till I saw your question.